# Entering the US twice on different passports

Tags: kuwait

Does it matter if I entered the US on my British passport 10 years ago and now I decide to visit the US but this time as a Kuwaiti?

I was told that US immigration may think that is odd.

Comment: Kuwaiti citizens require a visa to enter the US, see the US State Dept page here: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/travel-without-a-visa.html. UK passport holders can (mostly) travel visa-free. Why would you want to make your trip more complicated?

Comment: Who told you this?

Comment: Do you still have British citizenship and a valid British passport or did you become a Kuwaiti citizen?

Comment: @Freiheit those two options are not necessarily mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 12):

If you have a valid US visa in your Kuwaiti passport, you are more than free to visit using the other passport. If asked about other nationalities you can mention your British passport and the reason why you didn't want to use it (I presume you have one, such as the fact that its expired).

If you don't have a US visa, you can't use the Kuwaiti passport to enter the US and would have to either apply for one or enter using the British passport.

Answer (score 11):

They might think it's odd enough to ask you about it, especially in light of the fact that using your Kuwaiti passport means that you cannot use the visa waiver program.

But there's nothing illegal about it.  As long as you don't appear to be trying to hide anything, you shouldn't expect any significant delay solely because you are using a different country's passport.